# Simplify ${I}- {M} { A}^T( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)^{-1}{ A}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to simplify

$${I}- M A^T( I+AMA^T)^{-1} A,$$

where $ M$ is $(n \times n$) and $A$ is $(m \times n)$ matrices.

I think this should be  $( I+ AM A^T)^{-1}$, but not sure how to show it?

Also, do we have to assume that $M$ is invertible?

My conjecture is true for the scalar case.

Comment: Could you add some thoughts to your post that explains you proposed answer?

Comment: @amWhy From the scalar case.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Under the assumptions that $\|M\|<1$, $\|AMA^{T}\|<1$ and $AA^{T}=I$, you can show that your expression reduces to $(I+M)^{-1}$. This and other observations when $\|AMA^{T}\|<1$ strongly suggest the answer would be $(I+MA^{T}A)^{-1}$ in general

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$${I}- {M} { A}^T( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)^{-1}{ A}$$

You know that
$$( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)^{-1}(I+AMA^T)=I \\
( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)^{-1}AMA^T=I-( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)^{-1} \\
MA^T( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)^{-1}AMA^T=MA^T-MA^T( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)^{-1} \\
MA^T-MA^T( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)^{-1}AMA^T=MA^T( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)^{-1} \\
\bigl( {I}- {M} { A}^T( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)^{-1}{ A}\bigr)MA^T=MA^T( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)^{-1}
$$

Therefore, **assuming that**  $MA^T$ is invertible, you get
$${I}- {M} { A}^T( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)^{-1}{ A}=MA^T( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)^{-1} \left(MA^T \right)^{-1}$$

This shows that the expression is actually conjugated by $MA^T$ to what you expect.

**P.S.**
$$MA^T( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T) =MA^T+MA^TAMA^T \\
( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)MA^T=MA^T+AMA^TMA^T$$

Therefore, under the extra assumption that $A$ commutes with $MA^T$ you get that ${I}- {M} { A}^T( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)^{-1}{ A}=( {I}+{A}{M}{A}^T)^{-1} $.